# save method - doesn't flush the Session after an exception occurs

Tags: hibernate, playframework

```
public class SoftwareTest extends UnitTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Fixtures.deleteAll(); // will fail if comment that. why?????
    }

    @Test
    public void createSoftwareWithNullAuthor()  {

       // when author is null

       Author nullAuthor = null;

       Software software = new Software("software1", "description1", nullAuthor);
       try {
         software.save();
         fail("author should not be null");
       } catch (PersistenceException ex) {
       }

    }


    @Test
    public void createSoftwareWithOkAuthor()  {
       // when author is ok
       Author okAuthor = new Author("author1", "email1").save(); // ERROR HERE!

       Software software2 = new Software("software2", "description2", okAuthor);
       Software savedSoftware = software2.save();
       assertNotNull(savedSoftware);
       assertEquals(savedSoftware, software2); 

       assertNotNull(savedSoftware.author);
       assertEquals(okAuthor, savedSoftware.author);
    }
}
```

when uncomment the line with `Fixtures.deleteAll()` we will get en exception in second method - `createSoftwareWithOkAuthor()`  when `save()` the author. **Why that's happened?**

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in models.Software entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:82)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:190)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:147)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:240)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
  at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
  at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
```

Comment: I detailed the flow leading to this type of error here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062970/2087640

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the issue seems to be that Hibernate raises an exception (so the current transaction gets invalidated) but then you are trying to proceed with more operations in that session.

The proper way to do this would be to split the test you are using in 2, one part to test null authors and one to test with a valid author.

On production code (let's say a controller), you would need to restart the operation (close the transaction, relaunch the process) to be able to proceed. But given the way play manages transactions, the normal behavior would be that after the error you would just return with an error message to the user.

Comment: yes. this works, but i tried that also. but there is another problem then: in the @Before setup() method i have Fixtures.deleteAll(); if i comment this line there then i will have the same error in the second (splitted) method. here: Author okAuthor = new Author("author1", "email1").save();

Comment: How can we stop session to be no invalidate ?

Answer (score 11):

From the error:

> `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure`: `null id` in `models.Software` entry (don't flush the `Session` after an exception occurs)

We can see that **a session exception has happened before**. The point where this `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure` is thrown is not the point where the error ocurred.

That is: **Something is suppressing the original exception.**

So look for other possible points of error. A `save()` or `saveOrUpdate()` is possibly trying to persist an entity with a `null` field where, in the table, the column is `NOT NULL`.

In my case, the **real** exception was taking place inside a `try/catch {}` block where the `catch` suppressed the exception (didn't rethrow or warn me about it).

Answer (score 3):

**Maybe someone would repeat my mistake:**

I also come across with this problem. In my case the problem had occured because I set `column` type `integer`, and tried to wrote `long` value. After changing `column` type it start to work.

Comment: In my case, i had not put the ManyToOne and JoinColumn anotations