# Grails-null id in com.easytha.Student entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, grails-domain-class, grails-services

I have already seen several threads for this issue and none could rescue
I have the following in my DomainClass

```
def afterInsert() {     
        elasticSearchService.index(this)
}
```

Where elasticsaerch is a service and I have added it to the static transient list. It seems that after calling the index method successfully it throws this exception

```
Message: null id in com.easytha.Student entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

This is the code of index method

```
def  index(object) {
    try {
        if(object==null) {
            throw new NullPointerException()
        }
        if(!(object instanceof Collection || object instanceof Object[])) {
            IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex(grailsApplication.config.esIndexName, object.getClass().getName(),object.id.toString())
                    .setSource((object as JSON).toString() )
                    .execute().actionGet()
            println "object indexed successfully" 
        }else if(object instanceof Collection || object instanceof Object[]) {
            for (var in object) {
                index(var)
            }
        }
    }catch(e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

"object indexed successfully" is printed in the console.

The bootstrap.groovy has the following

```
Student student4 = new Student(firstName:'Sapan',lastName:'Parikh',email:'sapan.parikh@eclinicalworks.com',password:'test123')
    student4.save(failOnError : true)
```

---

**UPDATE**

I tried `Student.withNewSession { elasticSearchService.index(this) }` which worked.

Comment: what are you doing in your Bootstrap.groovy? you dint give that code here

Comment: @Motilal Added the bootstrap code, it's a simple save operation. Also there are no validation errors as well, I checked them by printing this.errors

Comment: add flush to your save () and try re-boot your app student4.save(flush:true, failOnError : true)

Comment: @Motilal nope still the same error.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298825/save-method-doesnt-flush-the-session-after-an-exception-occurs) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stabbing at things but maybe shift the save to happening within a transaction:

```
Student.withTransaction {
  student4.save()
}
```

I've seen this pop up unexpectedly when doing things outside of services (that should, imo, be in services).

Summing up some subsequent discussion:

The student model was saved throughout the application, so it wasn't suitable to shift all the saves to services or wrap in transaction blocks.  The OP notes that moving the original reindexing code into a new session fixed it everywhere.

```
def afterInsert() {     
    elasticSearchService.index(this)
```

}

Comment: Yes you are right, this solved the bootstrap issue but student.save is sprinkled all over the code base. Will I have to change it everywhere?

Comment: It worked with Student.withNewSession { elasticSearchService.index(this) }

Comment: That's probably going to solve an issue I have in some GPars code, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change your answer and I can accept it. It will be helpful for others?