# Facing exception "org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist" when I try insert data in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my spring appliucation, I am using Hibernate to deal with the operations with the database. Right now, when I try insert a registry in a table with a foreign key, I am getting an error. For instance, the table represented by this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pagina")
public class Pagina extends Entidade {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer Id;

    @Column(name = "nome", unique=true)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "titulo")
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name = "descricao")
    private String descricao;

    @OneToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_page")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Pagina pagina;

    @OneToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_product")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Produto produto;

}
```

I have this view to insert data in that table:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Pagina</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Cadastro de Pagina</h1>


    <form id="command" role="form" class="form" action="Pagina/cadastra" method="post">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>
                            <label for="nome" class="form-control">nome</label>
                            <input id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <label for="titulo" class="form-control">titulo</label>
                            <input id="titulo" name="titulo" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <label for="descricao" class="form-control">descricao</label>
                            <textarea id="descricao" name="descricao" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </p>

            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Pagina
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                        <input type="checkbox" name="Pagina.id" value="2">two<br>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="Pagina.id" value="1">one<br>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Produto
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                </div>
            </div>

        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
        </p>

    </form>

    <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;">
      <strong>Pronto!</strong> Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o efetuada com sucesso.
    </div>

    <div id="not" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
      <strong>Erro!</strong> N&atilde;o foi possivel efetivar a sua solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o.
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

which is handled by this methods:

**in the controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) {
    if(serv.cadastra(object))
        return "yes";
    else
        return "not";
}
```

**in the service class**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_'+#this.this.name)")
@Transactional
public boolean cadastra(E e) {
    return dao.persist(e);
}
```

if I try insert a item **without** select one of the checkboxes, the transaction is executed  correctly, but if I mark them, I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.spring.loja.model.pagina.persistence.model.Pagina entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.service.PaginaService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$df6523ad.cadastra(<generated>)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller.cadastra(controller.java:69)
    at com.spring.loja.config.generic.controller.controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8cc444b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)
    at com.spring.loja.model.pagina.controller.PaginaController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b87d072_2.cadastra(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't figure out why this happening. Anyone can point me in the right direction to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I made some modifications in my entity class and try some differents implementations for my Dao class, and still facing errors (but different errors). My entity class is now this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pagina")
public class Pagina extends Entidade {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer Id;

    @Column(name = "nome", unique=true)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "titulo")
    private String titulo;

    @Column(name = "descricao")
    private String descricao;

    @OneToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_page")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pagina pagina;

    @OneToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_product")
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Produto produto;
}
```

In my Dao class, I try this two implementations for my method `persist(...)`:

```
@Transactional
public boolean persist(E transientInstance) {
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
        return true;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Transactional
public boolean persist(E transientInstance) {
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(transientInstance);
        return true;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

with both options, if I try save an entity without no atribute Pagina or Produto, it's stored in the database with no problems. But if I try submit data with this atributes, I face problems.

with the first option, an exception `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist` is triggered, and with the second option, the data is stored in the database, but with error, since a extra row with no values are stored in the database, and the line with the data I inserted points to that line.

Anyone knows what's happening here? Because I have no clue.

Comment: Yes, i checked the database with the pgAdmin3 and the id was created correctly with the type `serial` and the sequences also was created with correctly.

Comment: I think the problem is because you are flushing the sesson before persisting the entity. Can you show your Dao layer?

Comment: yes, this is my Dao class: https://github.com/klebermo/loja.cms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/loja/config/generic/persistence/Dao.java

Comment: Change your Bean id generator to (@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)). And also try save rather than persist in DAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the update, I solve the problem described in this topic adding the line `e.printStackTrace()` to my `persist(...)` method in the Dao class. After that, I get the real error message and solve the problem following the instructions from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721688/org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-whe).

Answer (score 0):

Your application may be generating an exception which invalidates the Session, but your code continues to attempt to operate against the same Session as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5299279/1990536). I would check to see that you are handling any exceptions properly and introduce appropriate logging where needed to identify any exceptions details.